# How to use setState in external function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import Request from 'superagent';

const getApi = () => {
    let url = '/* URL */';
    return Request.get(url).then((res) => {
        this.setState({
             content: res.body
        });
    });
}

export default getApi;
```

I've created `function` in external file for `api call`. How do I get access to `function/setState` in external file?

```
componentWillMount(){
   getApi();
}
```

I receive this error:

> 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: pass a `callback method` into `getApi()` method and call that method once you get the response, do setState inside that callback method.

Comment: You can't, you need to return the response and then setState in the function

Comment: You should read [How does the “this” keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Solution:

```
function getApi(component) {
        let url = '/* url */';
        return Request.get(url).then((res) => {
            component.setState({
                content: res.body,
            });
        });
    }
```

---

```
componentWillMount(){
   getApi(this);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can pass in a callback to the `getApi` function from your component.

```
const getApi = (onSuccess) => {
    let url = '/* URL */';
    return Request.get(url).then((res) => {
        onSuccess(res.body);
    });
}
```

**Component**

```
componentWillMount(){
   getApi(this.setApiResponse);
}

setApiResponse(data) {
    this.setState({
        content: data
    });
}
```

NB. As your project grows larger, you may wish to look into a state management system, such as Redux.

Answer (score 1):

Technically you could pass the instance to `getApi` so that it knows what `this` is supposed to be. But imo. that's a poor approach. It creates unnecessary dependencies. At the moment, `getApi()` needs to know how the React class works; the function is responsible to manipulate the state of the Instance correctly.

Better if `getApi()` only returns the value, and the instance consumes it:

```
const getApi = () => {
    let url = '/* URL */';
    return Request.get(url).then(res => res.body);
}

componentWillMount(){
   getApi().then(content => this.setState({ content }));
}
```